# How to initiate a go struct with a nested struct whose name has package name

Tags: go

I have a go struct defined as below:

```golang
type Record struct {
    events.APIGatewayProxyRequest          `json:",omitempty"`
    events.APIGatewayWebsocketProxyRequest `json:",omitempty"` //nolint:all
    events.SQSEvent                        `json:",omitempty"`
}
```

I wonder how I can initiate this struct. I tried:

```golang
Record{events.APIGatewayProxyRequest: {}}
```

but it gives me an error: `invalid field name events.APIGatewayProxyRequest in struct literal`. It seems the name including package name can't be used as key name in the struct. What is the right way to initiate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you embed a type into a struct, the enclosing struct has a field name that is the same as the type name of the embedded type without the package selector. So:

```
event:=Record{
  APIGatewayProxyRequest: events.APIGatewayProxyRequest{ ... },
}
```

The right hand side of the initialization is a literal of that type, so you use the full type name (with the selector).